# Windows 11 source audio and Bluetooth audio volume levels not unified

Tags: audio, bluetooth, windows-11

On Windows 10, pressing the volume keys on my Bluetooth headphones directly controls the volume on the source device, instead of controlling the headphones' own independent volume level. I will hereby refer to this as the volume levels being "unified".

I upgraded my previous Windows 10 laptop to a new one running Windows 11.

On Windows 11, the volume levels are not unified. Also, the volume does not change when I slide the on-screen volume slider. The headphones still have an independent volume level, and this is the only way to lower the volume while Absolute Volume is enabled.

Every search result I've found tells me to disable Absolute Volume in the registry. This fixes the source volume not changing, but does not unify the volume levels.

How can I get my new laptop and my Bluetooth headphones to have unified volume levels, just like on Windows 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated Windows 11, and now the volume levels are unified. Seems like Microsoft finally fixed it.